# Python ModuleNotFoundError when trying to run main.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am pretty new to python and have been working on a data validation program. I am trying to run my main.py file but I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/data_validation/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.compile_csv import combine_csv_files
  File "/Users/user/data_validation/src/compile_csv.py", line 5, in <module>
    from helpers.helper_methods import set_home_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

I am using python version `3.94`

This is my folder structure

```
data_validation
       - src
         - files
              validation.csv
              - folder_one
                  combined.csv
              - folder_two
                  combined_two.csv
         - helpers
              helper_methods.py
           compile_csv.py
           mysql.py
           split.py
       main.py
```

Both `compile_csv.py` and `split.py` use methods from `helpers.helper_methods.py`

My `main.py` which is throwing the error when being run, looks like the following:

```
import os
import sys
import earthpy as et
from src.mysql import insert_data, output_non_matches
from src.compile_csv import combine_csv_files
from src.split import final_merged_file
from src.helpers.helper_methods import set_home_path, does_file_exist

home_path = et.io.HOME
file_path = home_path, "data_validation", "src", "files"
folder_name = sys.argv[1]


def configure_file_path():
    master_aims_file = os.path.join(
        file_path, "validation.csv")
    output_csv = os.path.join(
        file_path, "output.csv.csv")
    gdpr_file_csv = set_home_path(folder_name + "_output.csv")
    output_csv = does_file_exist(os.path.join(
        file_path, folder_name + "_mismatch_output.csv"))
    return output_csv, master_aims_file, gdpr_file_csv


output_csv, master_aims_file, gdpr_file_csv = configure_file_path()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(" Finding names which do not match name in master file")
    if (folder_name == "pd") and (folder_name == "wu"):
        final_merged_file()
    else:
        combine_csv_files()

    insert_failures = insert_data(output_csv, master_aims_file)
    output_failures = output_non_matches(output_csv, gdpr_file_csv)

    if insert_failures or output_failures:
        exit(
            "⚠️ There were errors in finding non-matching data, read above for more info"
        )
    os.remove(os.path.join(home_path, "data_validation", "members_data.db"))
    exit(
        f"✅ mismatches found and have been outputted to {output_csv} in the {folder_name} folder")
```

From what I understand in python 3 we do not need to use `__init__.py` and you can use `.` for defining the path during import, So I am not entirely sure as to what I am doing wrong.

I am executing the file from `/Users/user/data_validation` and using the following command `python main.py pd`

Comment: I think this is an issue with where you are executing the script at. Can you post exactly how you call `python` and what's ur pwd\cwd.

Comment: @Mythalorian I have updated the question and added the `cwd`

Comment: well your cwd and command is fine. Can you post the whole exception being thrown?

Comment: @Mythalorian added the whole exception now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There it is. The error is happening in your `compile_csv.py` file. I'm guessing in that file you have `from helpers.helper_methods import blah`. But you need to change it to

```
from .helpers.helper_methods import blah
OR
from src.helpers.helper_methods import blah
```

Reason being is that imports are relative to cwd not to the file where the code is running. So you need to add the import relative to `/Users/user/data_validation`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by setting PYTHONPATH variable. check more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pythonpath-environment-variable-in-python/)